# Kohana 3.1 ORM: Empty model property value saved as 0 (zero) instead of NULL

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have two models, Product and Product_Methodology. In my product edit view I have a select form field to select one of many methodologies or none (empty first option). In my products table I have a `INT(10)` `methodology_id` property that gets saved with the id of the methodology selected from the select form field. Everything worked OK until today that I had to make an adjustment to the system in which since now selecting a methodology can be optional. So I changed the `methodology_id` field of the products table to allow `NULL` value and removed the `not_empty` validation rule on the model.

**The problem is that now when I save the model selecting the empty option, instead of the expected `NULL`, I get a `0` (zero) value.**

Any clue on this?
Thanks a lot and let me know if it's not so clear.

Comment: What Kohana version you use? Ko3.1 has special filter methods for model fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What form input are you using for choosing the methodology? is it `<select>` ?
If so, the value of choosen option is probably set to 0 when no methodology is choosen, and send with other form data.

In such cases I make a custom filter withing model's `filters()` method, to set the value to NULL (as PHP treats it) when it's `empty()`, something like this:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'methodology_id' => array(
            array('Filter::null', array(':value')),
        ),
    );
}
```

Where Filter is helper class with static methods. like...:

```
class Kohana_Filter {

    public static function null($value)
    {
        return (empty($value) ? NULL : $value);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I chose this one as the correct answer because it is the most elegant solution to my mind. I believe the others are correct also.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the submitted form field is blank it's a string with any empty value - not NULL.  This gets cast as 0 when saved to an INT field (at least in mysql).  To preserve a null value do something like this:

```
$methodology_id = (empty($methodology_id) ? NULL : $methodology_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of using a closure to return a NULL value if the field value is an empty string:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        // Return a NULL value if empty string.
        'field_name' => array(
            array(function($value){
                return ($value === '') ? NULL : $value;
            }, array(':value')),
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is set the key for the **None** value in your select box to **0**.

You should leave the **not_empty** rule for the field. Then you should have a rule for the field that makes sure that the value is either a legitimate value for **product_methodology** or zero.

I extend ORM and have the following two functions:

```
public function exists_or_zero(Validation $validation, $field, $model, $pk)
{
    // The exists() function is only called if the field has a non-zero value
    if ($validation[$field]) {
        $this->exists($validation, $field, $model, $pk);
    }
}

public function exists(Validation $validation, $field, $model, $pk)
{
    if ( ! ORM::factory($model, $pk)->loaded()) {
        $validation->error($field, 'exists', array($validation[$field]));
    }
}
```

If you were to use these functions, you're rules in the **product** class would look like:

```
public function rules()
    return array(
        'product_methodology_id' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array(array($this, 'exists_or_zero'), array(':validation', ':field', 'product_methodology', ':value')),
        ),
    );
}
```